# Aligning column headers above my ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-studio

How can I align column headers above a ListView?

I created an xml file (list_item.xml) that contain the result and I created another xml file that contain the header of my ListView (header.xml..

1) "list_item.xml"

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/TableRow01"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/cf"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Codice Fiscale"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:height="40dp"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <TextView
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/cognome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cognome"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:height="40dp"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:layout_column="1"/>
    <TextView
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/eliminato"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Eliminato"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:height="40dp"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:layout_column="1"/>
    <TextView
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/esterno"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Esterno"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:height="40dp"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:layout_column="1"/>
    <TextView
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/idsogg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ID Soggetto"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:height="40dp"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:layout_column="1"/>
    <TextView
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/nome"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Nome"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:height="40dp"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:layout_column="1"/>
    <TextView
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/nomec"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Nome Completo"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:height="40dp"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:layout_column="1"/>
    <TextView
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/tiposogg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Tipo Soggetto"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:height="40dp"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:layout_column="1"/>
    <TextView
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/tiposogget"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Tipo Soggetto Etichetta"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:height="40dp"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:layout_column="1"/>
</TableRow>
```

2) "header.xml"

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/TableRow_header"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Codice Fiscale"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:height="40dp"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:background="#c0c0c0"
        android:layout_column="1"/>
    <TextView
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cognome"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:height="40dp"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:background="#c0c0c0"
        android:layout_column="1"/>
    <TextView
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Eliminato"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:height="40dp"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:background="#c0c0c0"/>
    <TextView
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Esterno"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:height="40dp"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:background="#c0c0c0"
        android:layout_column="1"/>
    <TextView
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ID Soggetto"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:height="40dp"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:background="#c0c0c0"
        android:layout_column="1"/>
    <TextView
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Nome"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:height="40dp"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:background="#c0c0c0"
        android:layout_column="1"/>
    <TextView
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Nome Completo"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:height="40dp"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:background="#c0c0c0"
        android:layout_column="1"/>
    <TextView
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Tipo Soggetto"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:height="40dp"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:background="#c0c0c0"
        android:layout_column="1"/>
    <TextView
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Tipo Soggetto Etichetta"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:height="40dp"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:background="#c0c0c0"
        android:layout_column="1"/>
</TableRow>
```

the problem is that the header is not aligned with list_item..

[image: header is not aligned to list_item]

How can I do to align the header with the list_item?
Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be causing an issue `android:layout_weight="0"`.
Here:

```
<TextView
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Codice Fiscale"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:height="40dp"
    android:textSize="17dp"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:background="#c0c0c0"
    android:layout_column="1"/>
```

Also mind that the weighted dimension (width, in this case) must be **0dp**, and **not** `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` (which, by the way is **deprecated** since API Level **8**), `android:layout_width="match_parent"` or `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`.